# Dúvida em Complexidade de Algoritmos

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Estou com uma dúvida em Complexidade de Algoritmos. Como podem ver, na imagem abaixo, as expressões são equivalentes, ou seja, possuem as mesmas qualidades e o mesmo termo dominante (n²), então porque os resultados são diferentes?

[image: Notação O]

Comment: Complexidade nada tem a ver com resultado, tem a ver com... complexidade.

Comment: Desculpa a minha ignorância, mas aquele símbolo em cima do `1` tem algum significado?

Comment: Resposta ao  lazyFox 2 - Negativo, o traço a cima do -1, era um 'p', da frase que o antecedia.

Comment: O (n^2) é quadrático e O(n^k) é polinomial no tamanho da entrada. Mas isso aí está parecendo um erro de digitação. =p

Comment: O que acontece em complexidade, é que se a função tiver muitos termos apos junta-los, tipo (x^3+3x^2+2x+5), você pega somente o maior termo da função (nesse caso x^3) pra representar a real complexidade, isso por que tendendo a função ao infinito, o resto acaba se torna irrelevante, veja: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3prowxx1qg

Comment: Nesse caso, também me parece um erro de digitação

Comment: Complicado, já possuo dificuldades nesta matéria, e a faculdade não está nem ai para os alunos... Agradeço pelos comentários e levarei a resposta para minhas dúvidas como um erro de digitação. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Tem como passar o enunciado de onde pegou isso? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvjon.png.
Ou a explicação anterior, do jeito que esta, esta meio vago

Comment: Resposta ao MarceloBoni - http://prntscr.com/el62k5 coloquei a página do pdf no lightshot

Comment: quando for mandar um comentário a alguém, basta escrever @+nome da pessoa :)
De fato, o certo ali era f = n^3 - 1 => f = O(n^3)

Comment: @MarceloBoni - entendido, de fato é um erro de digitação XD, obrigado pela atenção :D, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Isso talvez te ajude: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @MarceloBoni - Estarei lendo o conteúdo, mais uma vez, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, não está completamente errado. Tudo o que vou escrever aqui foi retirado do livro e das videoaulas de Cormen et al (2002).

Para começar, a notação Big-O (ou O-grande) serve-nos apenas para um "limite assintótico superior". É importante saber disso, pois a notação Teta (Θ) refere-se a limites assintóticos uma função acima e abaixo (ou seja, um limite assintótico "firme", ou "justo" em algumas traduções).

Quando se escreve normalmente que `f(n) = O(g(n))`, se está simplesmente afirmando que algum múltiplo constante de `g(n)` é um limite assintótico superior sobre `f(n)`. O Detalhe é que na notação big-O não há qualquer menção sobre o quanto o limite superior é restrito.

Ou seja, a notação diz que existe uma função `f(n)` que é `O(n<sup>2</sup>)` tal que, para qualquer valor de `n`, não importa o tamanho escolhido, o tempo de execução sobre essa entrada tem um limite superior determinado pelo valor de `f(n)`.

Em tese, portanto, uma função *f=n<sup>2</sup>-1* também tem um "limite superior" *não-restrito* de O(n<sup>3</sup>). Afinal, para todo n positivo, como n<sup>3</sup> é monoticamente crescente quando n > 0, vai existir constantes positivas c e n<sub>0</sub>, tais que 0<= f(n) <= cg(n), para todo n >=  n<sub>0</sub>.

Faça o teste!

Porém, não se usa a notação big-O dessa forma. Embora exista (e ela represente, de fato) um "conjunto de funções" que fazem a notação ser verdadeira (basicamente, nesse caso, toda função que tenha limite superior acima da função f por um fator c, polinomialmente), usa-se, sempre o limite assintótico mais "próximo".

Talvez tenha ficado confuso, mas a partir de 2:51 desse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjt_N9uYFI, Erik Demaine explica direitinho os "abusos" matemáticos da notação big-O (e o fato do sinal de igual ser assimétrico é um deles!) demonstrando como esses limites funcionam

De fato, ele usa o seguinte exemplo: 2n<sup>2</sup>= O(n<sup>3</sup>) e explica que isso, na verdade quer dizer que 2n<sup>2</sup> ∈ O(n<sup>3</sup>), ou seja que ela faz parte do "conjunto" de funções limitados assintoticamente por O(n<sup>3</sup>). Entende?

Ou seja, vc pode SIM, afirmar que g(n) = 3n<sup>3</sup> + 2n<sup>2</sup> + n é O(n<sup>4</sup>), mas essa afirmação é muito mais "fraca" ou imprecisa (ou melhor, "assintoticamente imprecisa") do que dizer que g(n) é O(n<sup>3</sup>), entende? Já que para provar, pela definição que  g(n) acima é O(n<sup>3</sup>) basta provar que ela é <= 6n<sup>3</sup>, para n>=0.

Espero ter ajuda a entender esse assunto, ao menos um pouquinho.

Qualquer dúvida, vá nos comentários!

Answer (score 0):

Não tem absolutamente nada de errado.

Se `f ∈ O(g)` e `g ∈ O(h)`, então `f ∈ O(h)`.

Ou seja, toda função `f(n)` pertence a `O(g(n))` se para todo `n` for verdade que `g(n) >= f(n)`.

É evidente que para todo `n` é verdade que `n^3 >= n^2`, então `f(n^2) ∈ O(n^3)`.