# Dois parâmetros diferentes que uma função aceita podem classificá-la como tendo complexidade O(n²)?

Tags: algoritmo, independente-de-linguagem, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Digamos que eu defina uma função da seguinte forma, que aceite um argumento `a` que seja um *array* bidimensional de números:

```js
function totalSum(a) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const elem of a) {
    for (const subElem of elem) {
      total += subElem;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

// Exemplo de entrada:
totalSum([[1, 2], [3, 4]]); // 10
```

Ela pode ser classificada como tendo complexidade O(n²), certo?

---

Agora no contexto de outra função, que aceita dois argumentos, `a` e `b`, ambos *arrays* unidimensionais:

```js
function allIncludes(a, b) {
  let allExists = null;

  for (const aElem of a) {
    // Note que o `includes` abaixo irá iterar sobre cada elemento de `b` até o
    // fim dos elementos, ou até que algum elemento seja igual a `aElem`.
    // Uma complexidade próxima de `O(n)`.
    if (includes(b, aElem)) {
      // Se `exists` já for `true`, irá continuar como `true`.
      // Se for `false`, não será atribuído.
      if (allExists === null) {
        allExists = true;
      }
    } else {
      allExists = false;
    }
  }

  return allExists;
}

// Ignore:
function includes(arr, elem) {
  for (const el of arr) {
    if (el === elem) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

// Exemplo de entrada:
allIncludes([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]); // true
allIncludes([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]); // false
```

Essa última função pode ser classificada com complexidade O(n²)? Pergunto isso porque, diferentemente da primeira função desta pergunta, `allIncludes()` irá aceitar dois argumentos, que podem ser de tamanhos diferentes.

Eu pessoalmente considero esse um caso de "quase O(n²)" ou "um pouco mais que O(n²)", mas com certeza essa denominação informal da minha parte não está correta.

Comment: Eu não sei se o título da pergunta é o mais ideal para esse caso. Se alguém quiser sugerir um título melhor, ficaria agradecido. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como melhorar o desempenho de meu código com "for"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268296/como-melhorar-o-desempenho-de-meu-c%c3%b3digo-com-for)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, acho que não. A minha pergunta não se trata de melhorar o algoritmo. Queria saber se os argumentos de uma função poderiam alterar a sua complexidade nos exemplos acima, e não como melhorá-las... Acaba que as respostas da outra pergunta acrescentam um pouco à esta pergunta, mas não creio que sejam duplicatas...

Comment: o problema foi a percepção de complexidade cúbica do autor da questão que linkei. O da sua é a aparência de complexidade quadrática. Como isso diferem as questões? Na minha visão, as respostas da pergunta que linkei respondem a sua, inclusive a do Maniero deu um deja vu quando eu vi por cima

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Já dá para dizer que não é O(n<sup>2</sup>) por uma razão básica, se você tem duas dimensões e cada uma pode ter um tamanho diferente (sim, é possível), só usar um `n` não faz muito sentido.

Na verdade o é `n` aí não é tão óbvio de acordo com o enunciado. O `n` na verdade é o `m` vezes `n`, onde `m` é a quantidade de elementos de uma dimensão e `n` é a quantidade de elementos da outra. Ou podemos apenas definir que `n` é a quantidade total de elementos da matriz. Então em relação ao total de elementos que deve avaliar a complexidade é O(n). Essa multiplicação que eu falei é só uma forma de achar o valor de `n`, mas você pode saber dela de alguma outra forma que dê a quantidade toda sem fazer conta alguma.

A complexidade deve ser medida de acordo com a quantidade total de elementos e não com a organização desses dados na memória. Esta estrutura de dados tem apenas `n` elementos.

O algoritmo é executado em cima desta quantidade e cada um deles é avaliado apenas uma vez, portanto a complexidade é **linear**.

Quando o tamanho das duas dimensões são iguais podemos dizer que a multiplicação dá o mesmo que `n` vezes `n` e por causa disto é n<sup>2</sup>, mas O(n<sup>2</sup>) é diferente de O(n<sup>2</sup>), neste caso especificado de mesmo tamanho das dimensões, e só neste de matriz quadrada, O(n<sup>2</sup>) == O(n).

Por isso que o correto é demonstrar a complexidade como O(n). Se usasse O(n<sup>2</sup>) só funcionaria para uma matriz quadrada, ou seja, dependeria da entrada que você não pode garantir.

Veja que colocando um contador de vezes que há uma avaliação dá a mesma quantidade de elementos total da matriz:

```js
function totalSum(a) {
  let total = 0;
  let contador = 0;
  for (const elem of a) {
      for (const subElem of elem) {
          total += subElem;
          contador++;
      }
  }
  console.log(contador);
  return total;
}

// Exemplo de entrada:
totalSum([[1, 2], [3, 4]]); // 10
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/BigOLinear.js).

O segundo é um algoritmo fundamentalmente diferente do primeiro, não importa aí a entrada (até importa no sentido que o algoritmo lida com coisas diferentes, mas não que a entrada em si faça a diferença na complexidade de forma direta).

Ele faz um pouco diferente e é um pouco mais complicado, ele costuma ser menor que linear na maioria dos casos.

Agora aqui a quantidade de avaliações depende dos valores que encontrar, dá para calcular a complexidade, mas a conta não é dentro desses padrões que usamos na maioria dos casos, é dada por uma fórmula mais complexa.

Lembrando que complexidade do Big O mede o pior caso, então podemos dizer que o segundo algoritmo é O(n<sup>2</sup>) já que há entradas que pode torná-lo **quadrática**.

```js
let contador = 0;

function allIncludes(a, b) {
    let allExists = null;
    for (const aElem of a) {
        // Note que o `includes` abaixo irá iterar sobre cada elemento de `b` até o
        // fim dos elementos, ou até que algum elemento seja igual a `aElem`.
        // Uma complexidade próxima de `O(n)`.
        if (includes(b, aElem)) {
            // Se `exists` já for `true`, irá continuar como `true`.
            // Se for `false`, não será atribuído.
            if (allExists === null) {
                allExists = true;
            }
        } else {
            allExists = false;
        }
    }
    console.log(contador);
    contador = 0;
    return allExists;
}

// Ignore:
function includes(arr, elem) {
    for (const el of arr) {
        if (el === elem) {
            return true;
        }
        contador++;
    }
  return false;
}

// Exemplo de entrada:
allIncludes([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]); // true
allIncludes([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]); // false
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/BigOQuadratic.js).

Answer (score 10):

A complexidade assintótica de um algoritmo refere-se a quantidade de iterações (mínima ou máxima) que são feitas baseado na quantidade de entradas para o algoritmo. Ademais, a sua complexidade preocupa-se com valores grandes para essas entradas (por isso o termo "assintótico"). Por exemplo, se o seu algoritmo recebe `n` elementos e executa alguma operação para cada elemento, então o algoritmo é linear, ou seja, limite superior `O(n)`. A sua primeira função tem complexidade linear, pois cada elemento é iterado apenas uma vez.

No seu segundo caso, o seu algoritmo percorre o arranjo `b` uma vez por cada elemento do arranjo `a`. É parecido com o seguinte:

```
para cada elemento x em a:
    para cada elemento y em b:
        faça algo com x e y
```

Para contar quantas iterações esse algoritmo faz, vamos assumir que `n` é a quantidade de elementos no arranjo `a`, e `m` é a quantidade de elementos no arranjo `b`. Como percorremos o arranjo `b` a cada elemento do `a` iterado, nós temos então `n` vezes `m` iterações. Portanto, a complexidade assintótica desse algoritmo é `O(n · m)`. Essa é uma complexidade *polinomial* e pode ser simplificada para `O(n²)` por ser um limite superior. O importante é notar que os elementos do arranjo `b` são iterados `n` vezes.

O seu segundo caso, então, é considerado polinomial, pois se você contar a quantidade de iterações feitas no total, você chegará na mesma complexidade `O(n · m)`. Veja só: `allIncludes` vai chamar `includes` para cada elemento do arranjo `a`, e `includes` percorre o arranjo `b` inteiro. A função `includes` é linear, `O(n)`, mas como ela é chamada para cada elemento do `a` em `allIncludes`, então a complexidade final acaba sendo polinomial.

Answer (score 5):

### Primeiro algoritmo

> Ela pode ser classificada como tendo complexidade O(n²), certo?

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é dizer ao que o seu `n` se refere. É a quantidade de linhas da matriz? A quantidade de colunas? A quantidade total de elementos?

Ele é `O(n)` sendo `n` a quantidade total de elementos na matriz.

Para demonstrar, vou modificar seu código:

```
function totalSum(a) {
  let total = 0;
  for (const elem of a) {
    for (const subElem of elem) {
      total += 1;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

Perceba que no miolo dos laços eu fiz ele somar sempre 1, dessa forma o retorno do código é a quantidade total de iterações.

Rode esse código algumas vezes com várias matrizes diferentes. Você deverá perceber que o valor retornado é sempre idêntico à quantidade de elementos na matriz. Ou seja, a quantidade de iterações executadas é exatamente a quantidade de elementos na matriz. Isso faz com que o algoritmo em questão seja `O(n)` onde `n` é o total de elementos na matriz.

Perceba que **não está errado dizer que este algoritmo é `O(n²)`**, pois toda função `f(x)` pertencente a `O(n)` também pertence a `O(n²)`, uma vez que o próprio `O(n)` pertence a `O(n²)`. No entanto, apesar de não estar tecnicamente errado, em análises assintóticas geralmente usa-se a menor função possível, ou seja, dizer que o algoritmo acima é `O(n²)` dá a entender que ele não é `O(n)`, sendo que ele é sim.

---

### Segundo algoritmo

É possível que a análise seja mais fácil se você falar o comportamento do algoritmo em voz alta:

> Para cada elemento no primeiro array, itere pelos elementos do segundo array

Perceba que o fato do algoritmo ter sido quebrado em duas funções é irrelevante para a análise, assim como aquele condicional dentro do `includes` também não importa, pois na análise de big-O considera-se o pior caso.

Dessa forma, espero que seja trivial concluir que o algoritmo pertence a `O(n*m)`, em que `n` e `m` são as quantidades de elementos em cada um dos arrays.

Caso queira simplificar ainda mais a conclusão da sua análise, você pode simplesmente considerar que ambos os arrays têm o mesmo tamanho, fazendo com que o algoritmo seja `O(n²)`.

---

Já respondi outras perguntas sobre análise assintótica, talvez você se interesse:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341120/98734
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/341089/98734

Comment: A matriz cresce de forma polinomial, pois não há um caso onde alguma linha da matriz tenha uma quantidade menor de valores do que a dimensão dela. Tanto é que a complexidade espacial de uma matriz é polinomial.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Uma matriz quadrada cresce em complexidade polinomial em relação à quantidade de linhas ou colunas (se tem 3 colunas, possui 9 elementos, se tem 4 colunas, possui 16 elementos etc). A análise que fiz do algoritmo usa como base a quantidade de **elementos** na matriz, não a quantidade de linhas ou colunas. O algoritmo claramente é linear em relação à quantidade de elementos na matriz.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Complementando: Talvez o fato de haver um laço dentro do outro venha a confundir, mas não se engane, o fato do algoritmo receber uma matriz é irrelevante, poderia ser um array unidimensional, não importa como os dados estão organizados em memória, o que importa é que cada elemento é visitado uma única vez, e é isso que torna o algoritmo linear.

Comment: Certo, faz sentido.

Comment: @Gabriel, a análise de complexidade assintótica é feita em cima dos parâmetros de entrada. Por exemplo, a soma de "números" representado por strings de dígitos em base arbitrária. Devo considerar que ele é um algoritmo linear ou logaritmo? A resposta é: depende do uso. Se eu quero saber em relação ao número `N` passado, então é logaritmo `O(log N)`, mas se é em relação à quantidade de dígitos daquele número `len`, então é linear `O(len)`.

Comment: Essas são variáveis codependentes, então alterar o valor de uma implica alterar o valor da outra. Para saber qual análise levar em conta, deve-se entender o que está sendo mensurado. Tem muitos casos em que saber que a complexidade é logarítmica é mais relevante do que linear, já tem outros casos que a verdade será o contrário