# Complexidade de algoritmo em Python com dois loops

Tags: python, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Esse algorítimo serve pra retornar o elemento que mais se repete numa lista:

```py
def algorithm_x(a):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        k = 1
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                k = k + 1
        if x < k:
            x = k
            y = a[i]
    return y
```

Eu não entendo porque a complexidade dele é considerada `O(nˆ2)` ao invés de `O(nˆ3)`, visto que no `for` externo você vai percorrer `n` vezes, no interno vai percorrer `n*n` vezes. Multiplicando os dois loops daria `n*n*n`. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O interno não percorrerá em `n * n`, em nenhum lugar mostra isso e é uma inferência sua que faz isso. Já que essa informação não existe no código, você que deveria dizer porque achou isso.

Se tem apenas um laço interno não tem como ele por si só ser polinomial. A não ser que alguma função interna nele na verdade fosse um laço mesmo sem você saber, mas não é o caso, todas funções (e operadores) executadas ali dentro tem complexidade O(1).

Inclusive dizer que é O(n^2) também está errado. A fórmula correta aproximada seria O(n*(n/2)) já que a cada passo ele vai começando percorrer os elementos mais pra frente até que no fim ele começa pelo último elemento, na média ele executa metade dos elementos.

O laço externo vai de 0 até o tamanho da coleção passada. Isso é fácil. Vamos dizer que a coleção tenha 6 elementos, portanto a faixa vai até 5, ela é exclusiva.

O laço interno primeiramente começará em 1 e vai até o 5. No segundo passo do externo o valor de `i` é 1, então o próximo laço interno começará do 2 e vai até 5. Na próxima vai do 3 até 5, e assim continua até que vai do 5 até 5. Portanto o primeiro percorreu 5 elementos, depois 4, então 3, aí 2, e finalmente 1. Somando tudo dá 15, e para calcular a média dividimos pela quantidade de interações (que foram 5), que dá 3, e que é metade de 6.

Eu dei uma [resposta que mostra isso com mais detalhes e um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/429559/101). Ali fica mais claro a desmistificação que a quantidade de laços usada sempre determina a complexidade. Em alguns casos sim, por isso não serve de modelo, serve como indicação inicial a ser investigada mais. Nos comentários da outra resposta eu mostro como o que parece ser uma complexidade pode ser outra se for mais a fundo, e coincidências não podem ser usadas para demonstrar a complexidade real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ainda não consegui compreender, porque no loop interno ele percorreria em média metade dos elementos, qual seria o pior input pra esse código? talvez um exemple me ajude a compreender.

Comment: @Pirategull editei pra explicar essa parte.

Comment: `O(n^2)` é equivalente a `O(n*(n/2))`. [Relembrando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969) [assíntotas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/268409/64969). Então, sim, pode-se dizer que o algoritmo apresentado roda em **ordem quadrática** e isso estará correto. Também se pode dizer que **rodará em função quadrática**, visto que qualquer polinômio de grau 2 é uma quadrática (incluindo fator constante e linear).

Comment: Também devo lembrar aqui que a notação Big-O trata-se de conjuntos, não de um polinômio em específico. Portanto, falar que `n^2 == O(n^2)` é um abuso comum de escrita, quando o correto seria usar `n^2 ∈ O(n^2)`. Como o conjunto descrito por `O(n**2)` é exatamente o mesmo que o conjunto definido por `O(n*(n/2))`, podemos escrever sem problemas que `O(n^2) == O(n*(n/2))`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não é, nem faz sentido, são valores completamente diferentes. Pode pegar qualquer valor de `n´, vamos pegar 6, a primeira fórmula dá 36 e a segunda fórmula dá 18. Você pode dizer que O((n^2)/2) == O(n*(n/2)). Eu não conheço bem as teorias disso, eu sei calcular o que interessa como engenheiro, e interessa a quantidade de passo s que faz, e o cálculo é assim. Se a teoria diz que O(n^2) == O(n*(n/2)), então ela serve nada pra mim, mas até duvido que a teoria diz isso.

Comment: Então você precisa urgentemente revisar sua teoria. Em se tratando de notação assintótica, quick sort é `O(n^2)`, mas não é por isso que você não usará ele para casos garantidamente aleatórios onde ele tem comportamento `O(n log n)`. Também vale ressaltar que a função dentro do grande O deve ser levada em consideração para quando a variável tende ao infinito, então substituir por 6 é simplesmente errado. Vale lembrar que o comportamento assintótico não tem a ver com quantas computações serão realmente feitas, é uma _assíntota_.

Comment: E, sim, o comportamento assintótico serve para mostrar o quão rapidamente vai crescer o tempo computacional de processamento, e não para dizer que haverão 18 comparações. Note que, se dobrar o `n` (ou seja, tomar 12 como entrada), ambos os cálculos serão uma multiplicação por 4: `12*12 = (6*2) * (6*2) = 6*6 * 4` e `12*12/2 = 6*2 * 6*2/2 = 6*(6/2) * 4`

Comment: Se for verdade eu não quero revisar a teoria, eu quero chutá-la pra bem longe, porque ela não me serve. Eu só quero saber em quantos passos (proporcionalmente e não em valores absolutos, claro) algo é executado, porque isso fará toda diferença no resultado final), qualquer coisa que me dê um número que não indica isso com clareza não me serve. Resultados teóricos não dão a noção que eu preciso para tomar decisões. Pode ser que esteja errado usar Big O pra isso, pode ser, me diga o que usar então pro que eu quero que é o que interessa de fato.

Comment: Você poderia dizer que `n**2/2 + n/2` _aproxima melhor_ o comportamento que `n**2`. Usar notação Big-O para isso é abuso (mas como dizer que `n**2 == O(n**2)` também é abuso e todo mundo faz). De toda sorte, em algoritmos mais complexos, muito comum usar que ele tem comportamento de acordo com `O(F(n))` se `n <= M` e `O(G(n))` se `M < n`. Isso se faz quando, para aquele intervalo de valores específicos, a constante que acompanha `F` ou `G` faz com que a função se torne desprezível de algum jeito.

Comment: É nessa linha de raciocínio que se diz que o `insertion sort` tem comportamento _linear_  para pequenos intervalos. E em cima desse fato o `Tim sort` consegue uma otimização de tempo absoluto em relação ao algoritmo base dele, o `merge sort`. E é levando em consideração os fatores multiplicativos que normalmente o `quick sort` rodará _muito_ mais rápido que o `merge sort`; mas sempre haverá aquele caso em que `selection sort` daria performance semelhante

Comment: Se me perguntam se aprender complexidade de algoritmo é útil e muita gente diz que nunca precisou. Eu sempre falo que usei a vida inteira. Posso ter usado errado, posso ter usado o termo indevidamente, mas isso que está falando nunca foi útil pra mim, e nunca usei de fato, eu usei o que eu sempre explico. E todo mundo entende. Eu sempre soube escolher as estruturas e algoritmos adequados fazendo as contas do jeito que sempre fiz porque elas me dão o resultado que importa, e aparentemente de forma mais precisa :)

Comment: Geralmente quando se fala de complexidade de algoritmos, estamos falando do "big O" que remove quaisquer constantes. O(n*(n/2)) = (0.5 n^2) = O(n^2). Há casos em que se está interessado no número exato de passos que o algoritmo vai dar, mas normalmente não. Se for para dizer o número exato ou médio de passos, a função é simplesmente n*n/2, não tem porque colocar o O() no meio.

Answer (score -1):

Quando a gente não entende um conceito, é interessante fazer um modelo:

```
n = 3
for a in range(0, n):
        for b in range(0, n):
                print ("a", a, "b", b)
```

A saída deste programa é:

```
a 0 b 0
a 0 b 1
a 0 b 2
a 1 b 0
a 1 b 1
a 1 b 2
a 2 b 0
a 2 b 1
a 2 b 2
```

Fica claro que a "complexidade" foi O(n^2), imprimiu 9 linhas (3 vezes 3).

Comment: Não é uma boa. O código https://ideone.com/pnYqb5 não é O(n^2), existe coincidência de algum caso específico onde m e n valerem igual poder falar que é n^2, mas está conceitualmente errado e observar esse modelo dessa forma passa uma ideia errada do que é complexidade de algoritmo. O código https://ideone.com/GMgVx7 é O(n) e faz a mesma coisa, o resultado observado não indica qual é a complexidade.

Comment: Ok, mas a pergunta era se dois loops aninhados produziam uma complexidade O(n^2) ou O(n^3), essa era a dúvida. E na minha visão você apenas "desenrolou' (unrolled) minha rotina. Daria pra fazer algo semelhante com um Bubble sort, "escondendo"  a complexidade elevando "n" ao quadrado e usando um único loop, o que não o torna O(n).

Comment: A sua resposta manda a pessoa criar um modelo que dá uma ideia falsa. Complexidade de algoritmo é isso, nem sempre a complexidade visível é a que ocorre de fato. O problema não é a pergunta, é a resposta que manda fazer algo que não só não a responde como induz a pessoa levar isso para outros casos que vão enganá-la, e ainda dá um exemplo diferente que não se encaixa no que está feito na pergunta. Passa a ideia que setem 2 laços é O(n^2), o que é uma possibilidade razoável, mas nem sempre ocorre de fato, que foi o que demonstrei no comentário.

Comment: Eu não falei que o Bubble sort pode virar O(n), eu disse que seu modelo não indica qual deva ser a complexidade, dei um exemplo que isso é furado, não dei um exemplo que isso funciona. Então é um modelo furado, um modelo não pode ser usado p/ provar algo quando hora ele funciona hora não. Sua resposta se baseia nele. Eu não disse q sua resposta mostra a complexidade errada, ela está certa (só não tem algo a ver com a pergunta, mas entendo ser um outro exemplo, a intenção não foi responder a pergunta), eu disse apenas que ela tira uma conclusão que não pode acontecer, só a conclusão é falaciosa

Comment: "Eu não entendo porque a complexidade dele é considerada O(nˆ2) ao invés de O(nˆ3)". Essa era a pergunta. E eu respondi, do meu modo.